# How to show variable's value in Dialog Name (Einstein Bot)

Tags: einstein, bots, einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots

please help me

I need show the Product's Name in the Menu, i think image talk all:

[image]

I have a menu, with two options, and the first show a text with a variable, but {!Product} don't works, there is a way of this work?

When i put {!Product} in Message or Question, this works normal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any solution for showing the variable in the title dialog, my solution was to change the message to "Know more about this product", I left a generic message.